# Reasons for not having a compact structure of an MVC application?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web-applications, architecture, directory-structure

In a web MVC project, I have the following structure:

```
mymvc/                      -> Project root.
    public/                 -> Document root. The only one folder accessible from web.
        assets              -> Client-side assets. NOT ONLY for global themes and libraries, BUT ALSO for each specific "view" controlled by the "src/Application" components.
            css/
            js/
            images/
            ...
        index.php           -> Application's entry point.
    src/                    -> UI layer rules.
        Application/
            Controller/
            View/
            ViewModel/
        Dispatcher/         -> Application dispatching - route matching, dispatching to the specified controller, etc.
        ...                 -> Other classes used by the components in the "src/Application" folder.
    templates/              -> Layout and template files.
```

Note: All domain model components (entities, repositories, data mappers, services, etc) reside in a folder outside of `mymvc` directory, so that they can be accessible by any other application, too.

I thought - a lot, actually - about doing the following two steps:

1. To move the `templates` directory to `src/Application` folder.
2. To move the `assets` directory to `src/Application`, to create an alias `/assets/` in the web server (Apache) configuration - pointing to the moved folder, and to allow full access from the external world to it.

The globally used assets - like css themes, or js libraries codes, or background images, or etc - could still remain located in the `public` directory - obviously not in a folder named or aliased `assets`.

I really find the two steps a very good idea, because, as I see it, both folders contain resources related to the structure from `src/Application`.
So, instead of having something like this:

- `src/Application/Controller/AboutUs.php`
- `public/assets/js/AboutUs.js`
- `templates/AboutUs/[multiple-layout-and-template-files]`,

a structure like the following seems to be much better:

- `src/Application/Controller/AboutUs.php`
- `src/Application/assets/js/AboutUs.js`
- `src/Application/templates/AboutUs/[multiple-layout-and-template-files]`,

But, after I studied many web frameworks, I realised that all of them keep the two folders (`templates` and `assets`) completely separated from the application folder.

So I'd like to ask: Are there any specific reasons, why my proposed moving of the two directories can not, or should not be done?

Thank you.

Comment: Surely your web resources (.js etc.) need to stay in the public folder to allow users to access them.

Comment: For the user(s) who will, maybe, decide to downvote my question: Be fair and let me know the motives of your downvote, so that I can change my question correspondingly. I am open to all your suggestions or critiques. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to achieve, and what your workflow is. You seem to be working in PHP - it's worth looking at non-PHP frameworks like Ruby on Rails.

Typically, you want an output folder to be "read-only" - the developer should not manually edit files, instead the build and deploy pipelines run tools like Gradle to convert SASS/LESS and JS files (from the `/source` folder) into CSS and minified/concatenated Javascript and place them in the correct location in `/public`. The build and deploy pipelines often have different configs for development and production builds (minifying only for production, for instance).

In Ruby on Rails, the structure is mostly as you describe as "much better" - except that "templates" is a folder underneath "views" called "layouts". There's a build step (which runs automagically) which converts the various asset files (SASS/LESS, JS etc.).

You can see a detailed description of the Ruby on Rails directory structure [here](https://github.com/jwipeout/rails-directory-structure-guide). Django's directory structure is explained [here](https://gist.github.com/santoshpurbey/364d88829ee6934c8275589d5b4e660b).

Answering the questions in your comments:

- **Where should the SASS/LESS/JS/Coffee script files go?** - Up to you. In Rails, they live in `/app/assets/javascript`s and `/app/assets/stylesheets`; in these folders, there is one file for each view, as well as application-level files. This makes your build process nice and simple - you have just 2 folders to worry about, and don't have to modify your build every time you create a new view.
- **How do I structure my views - I have application-level views and specific page views.** Again - mostly a question of convenience. In Rails, all the templates - live under `/app/views`. Application-level views live in a folder called `/app/views/layouts` - they are really not that different to the page-level templates, so moving them out of that folder doesn't seem to achieve very much, whereas keeping everything in the same top level folder makes build and configuration simpler.

So, no, there's no reason to do what you suggest.

Comment: Thank you, Neville. I appreciate! I extended my bounty for another week, because I have a feeling, that there are more aspects to be revealed.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion everyone could use a structure that suits him/her best.

I've been working with CodeIgniter a lot the past years and have been doing some juggling with files and folders myself. At the end I *think* I have the structure as I like it :)

For the application folder I, mostly, just stick with the recommended (basic) structure as in their manual and tutorials.

It looks like this:

```
- versionX
    - application
        - config
        - controllers
            - assets // Folder to keep asset specific controllers
                css.php
                js.php  // These controllers are bundling all resources and returning it as css, js or image file. Images can be cropped etc by params in url. Framework routes urls as domain.com/css/stylesheet.css to the css.php controller etc
                img.php
            documents.php // normal controller files
            users.php
            ...
        - core // core (controller) files from which controllers can extend
            APP_Controller.php
            APP_AssetController.php
            ...
        - helpers // Holds files with functions that you can use everywhere in the app.
        - libraries // Holds library files and folders
            PasswordHash.php
            Permissions.php
            Template.php
            Twitter.php
            ...
        - models // holds files with all DB logic (one file per DB table in my case, join tables not included)
    - public
        - css
        - js
            - components // javascript files for specific (large) page element(s)
                modal.js
                timeline.js
            - controllers // one js file per controller for controller specific js code
                documents.js
                users.js
            - resources // all libraries from 3rd party (Bootstrap, jQuery, ...)
        - uploads // user generated content (folder divided per file use/ origin)
    - themes
        - blueSky
            - views
                - layouts // app level views
                    - partials // app level partials (main navs, footers, ...)
                - documents // a folder per controller
                    - modals // modals used at document controller
                        _merge_document.php
                        _split_document.php
                    - partials
                        _form.php // for adding and editing documents
                        _drawer.php // submenu for document controller
                    index_view.php
                    create_view.php
                    edit_view.php
                    ...
                - users
```

I hope this gives you some idea on how I do it. But you realy should do what you like the most. Nothing worse than having to browse through something you don't like.

Comment: Okay! I forgot to mention, the index.php file ( for launching the app ) is directly under the versionX folder, just as .htaccess and other stuff like robots.txt ( versionX on live server could be public_html folder or you can add alias pointing to the versionX folder...

Comment: Thank you very much, Brainfeeder! I studied your answer and I hoped to be able to share the bounty. Unfortunately this was not possible. But please know that I really appreciate your effort. I found the part _" These controllers are bundling all resources and returning it as css, js or image file. Images can be cropped etc by params in url."_ an interesting one. Anyway, I extended my bounty for another week, because I have a feeling, that there are more aspects to be revealed.

Answer (score 1):

### Classify your code

The only thing that I would recommend is to keep the namespace equal to the directory structure to keep autoloading simple. From there, the language does not care how code is organised. *The* two limitations are namespaces and directories: these are hierarchical. So that determines that you can only classify code in a hierarchical structure.

The actual problem is that **hierarchical classification** is a problem in itself. Objects can be classified in many ways. Fortunately PHP is agnostic towards classification, so why can't humans be the same? Because we actually think about code and objects. We search for them, use them, nurture them. It's just a matter of personal experience and taste, what are your strongest associations with certain object behaviours?

There is one extra thing to consider: *"Hell is other people."*

Keeping your classification compatible with others, like that of the Symphony framework, will come in handy once your code starts to depend on that particular framework. Or the classification scheme of others can be something you are not willing to subject to.

Either way, **there is no reason *not* to do what you want**. If, later on, you change your mind, at least you'll know for yourself why you changed it and you will learn from it.

Comment: Thank you, Code4R7. I accepted Neville's answer, though I found yours an interesting one too.